# Get current month and date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have two dropdownlist that hold months and years...

```
$(document).ready(function () {               
     $('#Months option:eq(' + (new Date).getMonth() + ')').prop('selected', true);
      alert((new Date).getMonth());        
     $('#Years option:eq(' + (new Date).getFullYear() + ')').prop('selected', true);
      alert((new Date).getFullYear());
});
```

I wrote the JQuery script as above so that when my program runs the dropdown selected value must be the current month and year..

but when i execute the program..
the alert gives 7 and 2012.. but in my view the current month is selected but the current year is not why?? and how can I make my dropdown to select current year??

Comment: give some more code and post a demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
var d = new Date(),

    n = d.getMonth(),

    y = d.getFullYear();

$('#months option:eq('+n+')').prop('selected', true);

$('#years option[value="'+y+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

**HTML**

```
​<select id="months">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="years">
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z9RZp/)**

Comment: small detail, getMonth() returns a value from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Months are returned as an integer from 0 (January) to 11 (December): see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0240__Date/DategetMonth.htm</strike>

<strike>So the current month (August) would return 7. To be able to match up with the usual month index (meaning 1 to 12), use `((new Date()).getMonth() + 1)`.</strike>

As pointed out in the comments, I misunderstood the problem. The month is correct because of the zero-based array for months and the jquery selector `:eq()` being also zero-based.

However as pointed in other answers, the year returned would not match `:eq()` which matches the nth element in the jquery selector. Using as suggested `option[value=' + (new Date).getFullYear() + ')'` would be better.

Comment: OP has problems with the current year : " in my view the current month is selected but the current year is not why??"

Comment: i didn't mean that in my dropdown list it shows August but i want to show 2012 in my second drop down list... as it is showing the minimum value i.e. 2007..

Comment: @nemesv: i want to ask the same question??

Comment: ``:eq`` is also 0-based, so OPs code is actually correct and selects 8th Month for value getMonth() == 7.

Answer (score 1):

The `:eq(N)` part of the selector in jQuery selects Nth element (including 0th) in the matched set (which at that point would be `#Years option`). So unless you have more then 2012 options in the `Years` dropdown, this won't work.

It's better to select the option based on it's value: `option[value=2012]` or

**[just use `$("#Years").val(2012)`](http://jsfiddle.net/9VEFt/2/)**, it's more readable and less code.

Comment: @sna2stha: And? Your alert just shows the current year, not which option got selected.